# Excel Table: Conditional formatting based on comparison of two columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

How can I set the format of one column based on a comparison of two columns?  For example, consider the table named "T" below. Suppose I want to set the format of column B. Using formula-based conditional formatting

This works:   =INDIRECT("T[@A]") > 3

but this does not:  =INDIRECT("T[@A]") > INDIRECT("T[@B]")

[image]

Comment: It works for me.  I cannot reproduce.

Comment: @ScottCraner   Thanks very much for trying it.  Suddenly it works for me, too.  I'm not sure what I was doing wrong.  It's possible I set the range incorrectly, but I'm sensitive to the need to get that right.  I spent quite some time trying and not succeeding to it to work. If I can find a failure case that occurs in common use, I'll update the question.